# Less than symbol in web service response c#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I am in the process of creating a web service in C# which is consumed by a java third party application. one of my response value contains less than "<" symbol and it's getting converted to "&lt" and looks like the java application cannot handle or unable to transform them back to "<" symbol. It works fine when I consume the response in a .Net application and display the value. I tried to add CDATA and it doesn't go as expected.

Actual Message

```
 Date <X1> is too old.
```

Code to add CDATA

```
response.Message= "<![CDATA[" + row.Message+ "]]>";
```

Also Tried

```
response.Message= "![CDATA[" + row.Message+ "]]";
```

Without CDATA (output from SoapUI)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetMessageResponse xmlns="http://xxxx.com/">
         <GetMessageResult>
            <Message>Date &lt;X1> is too old.</Message>
         </GetMessageResult>
      </GetMessageResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```

With CDATA (output from SoapUI)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetMessageResponse xmlns="http://xxxx.com/">
            <Message>Date &lt;![CDATA[&lt;X1>]]&gt; is too old.</Message>
         </GetMessageResult>
      </GetMessageResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```

What am I missing or is there any way to pass the "<" symbol without transformation. As I said it's a third party application which we don't have any control. Appreciate your time and answers.

Comment: See wiki for list of html special characters : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references  To correct use :   System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding of your message as

```
<Message>Date &lt;X1> is too old.</Message>
```

is the correct encoding.  The SOAP library is going to encode whatever text you have in your response message.  Trying to wrap it in CDATA is just going to encode that for XML, as it should, and as you have observed.

If you didn't encode the `<` as `&lt;` it wouldn't be valid XML, and it would think `<X1>` was a nested element rather than text.

If you are successful in coercing the framework to use CDATA encoding rather than plain XML escape sequences for encoding your message (there may be a hidden setting somewhere, but I'm not familiar with it), even CDATA can't encode everything-- specifically the sequence `]]>` cannot be represented in a CDATA block.  If your 3rd party application doesn't parse escape sequences properly, then you can assume it was written by someone who didn't understand XML and is very likely that it doesn't understand CDATA blocks anyway.

If you have no control over the 3rd party application and it really can't parse XML correctly, your best bet is to sanitize your message to not include the less than sign or ampersands, to avoid encoding problems.  The `&` and `<` symbols *must* be encoded in XML, but there are other optional escape sequences as well, that you might have to avoid if the SOAP framework emits them-- `&quot;`, `&gt;` for example.

Your only other choice, I am afraid, is to write your own SOAP / XML encoder that produces either CDATA blocks (and doesn't allow `]]>` to be transmitted) or malformed XML with a `<` symbol in the middle of element content that your 3rd party application can understand-- but there might simply be no way for an application that doesn't parse XML correctly to understand a `<` symbol in the content of an element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are planning to replace < symbol to [. I hope that should not have any problems. There's no CDATA.  Let me know.

Comment: Replace `&` too, just in case.  It will turn into `&amp;`

Comment: Thanks. I just cross checked and there is no &